# How can I apply style to multiple li in Ckeditor4

Tags: list, ckeditor, styles

I'm added my ckeditor my styles

{ name: "Indent 50px", element: "li", attributes: { "class": "indent50" } },

and it works when a put cursor on li line and select style
but I can't select multiple lines and applay it to all at once?